# How to close a non-reponsive dialog when it's secondary dialog is hidden?

Tags: drivers, dialog

I was in the process of installing "Additional Drivers" when I encountered an error and I was informed to review a log. I left the notification dialog open while I switch to a terminal but when I switched back, the notification dialog was missing/hidden, now the primary dialog won't close. I can't find the hidden notification dialog even if I minimize everything nor can I find the process PID that the dialog box belongs to? In even likes these, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal (open a terminal window with CTR+ALT+T)

type:

```
kill $(pgrep name-of-application-here)
```

example:

```
kill $(pgrep drivers)
```

This will kill all processes that have that phrase in the title

pgrep returns the pid # number of a process that you know the name of.

Try:

```
pgrep terminal
```